# PHP script stops execution in 5 min

Tags: php, linux, apache, terminal

I am running a php script from terminal it stops execution in 5 minutes.

max_execution_time value in ini is 600.

And I have also added set_time_limit(0) at the top of the script

Then also it ends in 5 minutes. The same happens when running from browser also

Comment: Any other errors that you see in log file like memory usage etc.?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); ` Have you tried this?

Comment: I had tried this also ini_set('max_execution_time', 0) , but no change. let me check the log file for memmory issues. which log file ?, the same apache error log file ..?

Comment: What is the script doing for such a long time?

Comment: If you are running the php script in cli, then it will be using a different php.ini. On your script, add `var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time'))` to see the limit it's running under.

Comment: that log file: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log  and while being at it also take a look at the error reporting level: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: reading csv file with around 2500 rows,25kb file size. read each row, create some objects, mysql queries to retrieve,add,update. looping through each row. stops execution at around row 480.

Comment: @LajeeshKallidukkil are you using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to parse the CSV and importing the data using bulk insert / transaction? If not, that's why your script is taking a long time,

Comment: Yeah, I am sure you could optimize that. Can you show some code?

Comment: using this class for parsing csv https://github.com/jimeh/php-parsecsv/blob/master/parsecsv.lib.php , not fgetcsv

Answer (score 1):

See if values are overwritten with phpinfo() after the max_execution_time and set_time_limit(0)

Comment: set_time_limit(0);
echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); used this and find it is set to 0

Answer (score -1):

try this and check if anywhere u made override or not

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```